# Why Ignite Connector throws IgniteCheckedException for reconnection for affinity nodes?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite, distributed-computing

My kafka-ignite connector suddenly stopped because the Ignite server got restarted. And when I restart my connector it is throwing same error regarding affinity node for particular data. It is not getting node details for a particular partition. This is something I understood by the exception stack trace. Please find the attachment and help me.

Thanks.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data streamer has been closed.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.closedException(DataStreamerImpl.java:1102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.lock(DataStreamerImpl.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addDataInternal(DataStreamerImpl.java:647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addDataInternal(DataStreamerImpl.java:632)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addData(DataStreamerImpl.java:754)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask.put(IgniteSinkTask.java:114)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to get affinity nodes [aff=AffinityInfo [affFunc=RendezvousAffinityFunction [parts=1024, mask=1023, exclNeighbors=false, exclNeighborsWarn=false, backupFilter=null, affinityBackupFilter=null], mapper=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheDefaultBinaryAffinityKeyMapper@5c3c8bba, assignment=GridAffinityAssignment [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], super=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityAssignment@193], cacheObjCtx=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext@44a4e9d], key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=276, val=Person(name=123), hasValBytes=true]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.primary(GridAffinityProcessor.java:686)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.affinityMap(GridAffinityProcessor.java:649)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.keysToNodes(GridAffinityProcessor.java:382)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.mapKeyToNode(GridAffinityProcessor.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.nodes(DataStreamerImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.load0(DataStreamerImpl.java:902)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.access$1500(DataStreamerImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5$1.run(DataStreamerImpl.java:997)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5$2.call(DataStreamerImpl.java:1024)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5$2.call(DataStreamerImpl.java:1012)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:7085)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:971)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    ... 3 more
[ERROR] 2021-09-10 15:56:28,439 [task-thread-map_2-0] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask doRun - WorkerSinkTask{id=map_2-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:614)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data streamer has been closed.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.closedException(DataStreamerImpl.java:1102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.lock(DataStreamerImpl.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addDataInternal(DataStreamerImpl.java:647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addDataInternal(DataStreamerImpl.java:632)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.addData(DataStreamerImpl.java:754)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.connect.IgniteSinkTask.put(IgniteSinkTask.java:114)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to get affinity nodes [aff=AffinityInfo [affFunc=RendezvousAffinityFunction [parts=1024, mask=1023, exclNeighbors=false, exclNeighborsWarn=false, backupFilter=null, affinityBackupFilter=null], mapper=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheDefaultBinaryAffinityKeyMapper@5c3c8bba, assignment=GridAffinityAssignment [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], super=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityAssignment@193], cacheObjCtx=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext@44a4e9d], key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=276, val=Person(name=123), hasValBytes=true]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.primary(GridAffinityProcessor.java:686)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.affinityMap(GridAffinityProcessor.java:649)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.keysToNodes(GridAffinityProcessor.java:382)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.affinity.GridAffinityProcessor.mapKeyToNode(GridAffinityProcessor.java:293)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.nodes(DataStreamerImpl.java:1124)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.load0(DataStreamerImpl.java:902)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl.access$1500(DataStreamerImpl.java:132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5$1.run(DataStreamerImpl.java:997)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5$2.call(DataStreamerImpl.java:1024)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamerImpl$5$2.call(DataStreamerImpl.java:1012)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:7085)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$2.body(GridClosureProcessor.java:971)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
```

My Server configuration is:

```
 <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    
    <property name="workDirectory" value="/ignite/work"/>
    
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="walPath" value="/ignite/wal"/>
        <property name="walArchivePath" value="/ignite/walarchive"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
          <property name="name" value="myCache"/>
          <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
            <constructor-arg>
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration">
                <property name="namespace" value="myspacename"/>
                <property name="serviceName" value="myservicename"/>
              </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

My connector is a thick client using an XML configuration file default config and just discovery spi.

Another question is this error is throwing when my Ignite pod is getting restarted due to full memory? Can I change its behavior to put data in persistence not in memory? Or what's an idle way to resolve this if it is getting restarted due to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you enable persistence, your data should offload to a disc, and ignite should not restart. Could you show what error in logs which leads to restart?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Kafka connector can not determine a primary node for key

`key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=276, val=Person(name=123), hasValBytes=true]`

Try to determine what node correspond this key:

```
ignite.affinity(cacheName).mapKeyToNode(key);
```

Comment: Hi, I am not using java for transmission of data, I am using apache ignite connector. My client is defined in xml configuration file which is a parameter of connector properties. In this case, how can I configure affinity?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question and added one observation. Please check